# shell script to change .pdf files to .png Mac OS 10.3

Tags: image, macos, bash, scripting

I'd like to make a script on Mac OS 10.3 that converts a pdf to a png. I've been looking around but I'm not sure if its even possible. I keep reading about a "sips" command but it doesn't seem to be available on 10.3, or at least this one. I typed man sips in the terminal and nothing came out.
I have written a couple bash scripts and kind of understand how they work but was hoping this specific issue at work would be a good way to practice. I could probably write something that changes the name, but I'm not sure that would work in and of itself as the new png file would probably not actually work.
Is there a way from the terminal to basically open preview, open each file and then save as a png? that would probably be the best option.
Thanks

Comment: sips would be a great tool to use (and the command would be `sips -s format png infile.pdf --out outfile.png`), but it looks like it started being included in 10.4 (Tiger).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't have a suitable system to test on, but I *think* `sips` appeared in 10.3.  (It's definitely in 10.4.)

Just because there is no man page doesn't mean that it isn't there (try `sips -h` or `ls /usr/bin/sips`).

If it's there, Sorpigal's answer (+1) is good for the basic scripting, but replace

```
convert "$pdf" "${pdf%%.*}.png"
```

with

```
sips -s format png --out "${pdf%%.*}.png" "$pdf"
```

Comment: so I got sips to work on the command line but I can't get it to work in a script. it says 
Warning: *{pdf, not a valid file - skipping
Error 4: no file was specified
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool

Comment: I can't see any obvious way of getting that exact error message unless you have omitted the `shopt -s nullglob` *and* put a space after the comma in `*{pdf,PDF}`.  (Unless it's something weird with the version of `bash` in 10.3, which I guess is quite ancient.)

Comment: I can't tell anymore since I changed it, but I bet theres a good chance it was a space. that has tripped me up in sh scripting before. I'm really used to java and c++ and generally not caring enough about spaces.

Answer (score 13):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) can do this

```
convert "your file.pdf" "output file.png"
```

You will have to install it since it's not available by default.

If you want to convert a large number of files, add a for loop

```
cd /some/directry/with/pdfs
shopt -s nullglob
for pdf in *{pdf,PDF} ; do
    convert "$pdf" "${pdf%%.*}.png"
done
```

Which will create equivalently named PNG files for each PDF with a .pdf or .PDF extension in that directory.

Comment: Note that PDFs are vector graphics, while PNGs are raster graphics. Converting from one to the other is not trivial, and it will probably take some tweaking of size, depth and color-profile settings to get the output that you're expecting.

Comment: I'm using sips instead of ImageMagick but the conversion its doing seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following shell script.

1. Make bash file e.g., `test.bash`

`for i in *.pdf; do
  name=$i;
  name=${name%.*};
  sips -s format png $i --out ${name}.png;
done`

2. Enter the command

`bash test.bash`

Answer (score 0):

10.3 is somewhat old, so can't try solutions.

But here is a tutorial http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.03/BasicImageManipulation/index.html
how to convert via applescript and built-in Apple ImageEvents (what comes with 10.3). Simply try change the jpeg/tiff to pdf/png.