# shell script to change .pdf files to .png

Tags: bash, scripting

Not sure how to ask a question about a previous posted question so if I should just add to the previous question somehow feel free to tell me.
Anyway, I posted a question yesterday
[shell script to change .pdf files to .png Mac OS 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349984/shell-script-to-change-pdf-files-to-png-mac-os-10-3)

sips does work and if I do it on the command line one file at a time it works but my for loop isn't working

heres what I got

```
for pdf in *{pdf,PDF} ; do
    sips -s format png --out "${pdf%%.*}.png" "$pdf"
done
```

and its saying

```
Warning: *{pdf, not a valid file - skipping 
Error 4: no file was specified 
Try 'sips --help' for help using this tool
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me. Are you sure you are using bash to execute this script and not `/bin/sh`?

Make sure your first line is:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Try echoing the files and see if it works:

```
for pdf in *{pdf,PDF} ; do
    echo "$pdf"
done
```

Comment: If I run this code it prints out 
    *{pdf,
    PDF}
do I have something not set up right. cuz I kinda feel like this is related to what its doing in my other version

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is bash you can do this

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

This changes the behavior of bash when no globs match. Normally if you say `*pdf` and there are no files ending in "pdf" it will return a literal asterisk instead. Setting `nullglob` makes bash do what you would expect and return nothing in such a case.

Alternately, and more robustly, you could do it this way

```
for pdf in *[pP][dD][fF] ; do 
    sips -s format png --out "${pdf%%.*}.png" "$pdf"
done
```

Which should work without nullglob being set and in all shells that support parameter substitution with this syntax. Note that this is still not robust on case sensitive filesystems due to a risk of name collision if you have two PDF files whose names differ only due to the case of the extension. To handle this case properly you could do

```
for pdf in *[pP][dD][fF] ; do 
    sips -s format png --out "${pdf%%.*}.$(tr pPdDfF pPnNgG <<<"${pdf#*.}")" "$pdf"
done
```

This should be sufficiently robust.

EDIT: Updated to correct incorrect `$pdf` expansion in the extension.

Comment: Thanks, Not sure why but this works where as *{pdf,PDF} did not.

Comment: @FunBeans: I explained why. It has to do with the expansion of globs. You need to either say `shopt -s nullglob` first or to do something which doesn't fail in the same way, which is why the alternative works.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED2**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Patters patching no files are expanded into null string
# this will allow us to make this script work when no files
# exist in this directory with this extension
shopt -s nullglob

# Consider only the lowercase 'pdf' extensions and make them lowercase 'png'
for b in *.pdf
  do
    c="$b"
    b="${b/.pdf/}"
    convert"$c" "$b.png"
done

# Consider only the uppercase 'pdf' extensions and make them uppercase 'png'
for b in *.PDF
  do
    c="$b"
    b="${b/.PDF/}"
    convert "$c" "$b.PNG"
done
```

Note that the `convert` program is a part of the `ImageMagick` program.

Comment: this just changes the file extension - not the actual file format

Comment: OOH man i completely misread it. i though the asker needs to change the file extension.

Comment: This is a bad idea. If you have both `foo.pdf` and `foo.PDF` you will only get a single `foo.png`; one will be lost. This presumes a case sensitive filesystem. To get the correct behavior you'll want to upper-case the PNG extension for cases where the PDF is upper case.

Comment: This will work, but see my answer for a more elegant (read: harder to understand) way to match case on the extension.

Comment: @Sorpigal : i do not claim that my answer is better. The thing you have is that mixed cases would be also supported, and it is a very good point, but is rare, but i have done a +1 to you for that

Comment: I was not attempting to be critical. You've improved yours to the point where it meets the needs of the original poster, which is all to the good.

Comment: @Sorpigal: The cause i did not use the set matching is that it did not strike me as mixed cases are a bit rare. Being critical i think is good, it helps make a good community and improve skills, i appreciate your comment.